# Reading XML data using DOM in Java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to get data from the below XML.

```
    <vehicle>
        <id>vehicle</id>
        <frame>
            <material>plastic</material>
```

When I read the data from the frame tag, how do i get the value of frame tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch only the "Frame" tags using doc.getElementsByTagName("frame") and then print the value of their child "Material" tags.

Comment: You have to make some more changes. The method getFirstChild() returns a text element and not the material element. For every frame element, fetch the list of children nodes (using getChildNodes()), and then iterate over this list to find the material tag and retrieve its value.

Answer (score 0):

`frameList=  doc.getElementsByTagName("material");`

Should be

`frameList=  doc.getElementsByTagName("frame");`